# How can I recolor an object to white in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

Like say I have a picture of a cut orange, and I want the inside pulp to be colored white instead of orange? I want to keep the details of the pulp, similar to how colorizing works. I've tried using colorize, but that only supports colors that are not white or black.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following method.

1. You can add a new transparent layer above the orange image layer and draw over the part you want to change the color of in the color you want to change it to. In this case, white.

[image: Initial Image]
[image: New layer]

2. Change the new layer’s blend mode to “color”.

[image: Set layer blend mode]

3. At this point, the image may be fine when using some colors but if the image looks like it still needs more of that color, duplicate the layer and set its blend mode to “overlay”. Repeat this until you are happy. You can also change the opacity of the layer to get a color between the previous and the next.

[image: Color layer applied]
[image: Overlay layers]

The results:

Before:[image: Before coloring]
After:[image: After coloring]

In there case of the orange, you can also blur each layer to make the edges blend better for a more natural look.

[image: Layers blurred]